# Ошибка xml в админке Opencart

Tags: xml, opencart

При входе в админку Opencart выводит массу ошибок
[image: ошибки]

Указывает на строку:
`$currencies = simplexml_load_string($content);`

Также слетел весь русский язык[image: слетел язык]

Answer (score 0):

Решилось переходом на любой пункт меню в админке (ошибки пропадают, но как только перезагружается страница все возвращается) и открытием FileZilla (ошибки пропали вообще).